# Spark Structured Streaming writestream doesn't write file until I stop the job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming on a classic use case : I want to read form a kafka topic and write the stream into HDFS in parquet format.

Here is my code :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, DataTypes, StructType}

object TestKafkaReader extends  App{
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("Spark-Kafka-Integration")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  import spark.implicits._

  val kafkaDf = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","KAFKA_BROKER_IP:PORT")
    //.option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()

  val moviesJsonDf = kafkaDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

  // movie struct
  val struct = new StructType()
    .add("title", DataTypes.StringType)
    .add("year", DataTypes.IntegerType)
    .add("cast", ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType))
    .add("genres", ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType))

  val moviesNestedDf = moviesJsonDf.select(from_json($"value", struct).as("movie"))
  // json flatten
  val movieFlattenedDf = moviesNestedDf.selectExpr("movie.title", "movie.year", "movie.cast","movie.genres")


  // convert to parquet and save to hdfs
  val query = movieFlattenedDf
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("parquet")
    .queryName("movies")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "src/main/resources/chkpoint_dir")
    .start("src/main/resources/output")
    .awaitTermination()
  }
```

Context :

- I'm running this directly from intellij (with a local spark
  installed)
- I manage to read from kafka without problem and write in
  console (using console mode)
- For the moment I want to write the file
  on local machine (but I did try on HDFS cluster, the problem is the
  same)

My problem :

During the job, it doesn't write anything in the folder, I have to manualy stop the job to finally see the files.

I figured that there is maybe something to do with `.awaitTermination()`
For information, I tried to delete this option but without that I get an error and the job simply doesn't run.

Maybe I didn't set the right options but after reading many time the doc and searching on Google I didn't find anything.

Can you please help me on that ?

Thank you

EDIT :

- I'm using spark 2.4.0
- I tried the 64/128mb format => nothing change no file until I stop the job

Comment: What is your spark version?

Comment: could you try to write 64MB/128MB data? for instance maybe you are facing a similar issue with this [one](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/80123/streaming-ingest-to-hdfs.html)   or alternatively set the hdfs.rollSize to a smaller value. I believe there might be a similar configuration in Spark as well

Comment: I update the post with spark version

Comment: Hello @Yrah how much data are writing to the output stream at the moment? with the rollSize  specification set to 64MB you must write out at least 64MB in order the write out process take affect. You can set this to a small number if you don't want to wait your application writing 64MB

Comment: Hello @AlexandrosBiratsis ,  I'll give it a seconde try, maybe I did something wrong. 
How can I set the parquet size please ?

Comment: you could try by setting the parquet.block.size option as here: 
`block_sz = 1024 //1KB
val query = movieFlattenedDf
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("parquet")
    .queryName("movies")
 .option("parquet.block.size", block_sz)
    .option("checkpointLocation", "src/main/resources/chkpoint_dir")
    .start("src/main/resources/output")
    .awaitTermination()`

Comment: Hi, did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes problem solve

My problem was that, I had too few data and spark was waiting for more data to write the parquet file.

To make this work I use the comment from @AlexandrosBiratsis
(change the block size)

Once again all credit to @AlexandrosBiratsis
thank you very much